# Question about inflection points and the second derivative test

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)$, is a twice differentiable function, and $f"(x)=0$ at $x=c$, then $f(x)$ has an inflection point at $x=c$.

Does the above statement always apply? It seems so to me, because if the second derivative is set equal to zero, and there is a solution, then there must be an inflection point. Can anyone provide a counterexample or does this always hold?

inflection Point: "a point on a curve at which the curve changes from being concave (concave downward) to convex (concave upward), or vice versa"

Comment: What is your definition of an inflection point?

Comment: $f(x) = x^{4}$..

Answer (score 1):

Given sufficient differentiability, an inflection point of $f$ is a locla extremum of $f'$; and a local extremum of $f'$ is a point where $f''$ changes signs. Does a function *necessarily* switch signs at its zeroes?

Answer (score 0):

No this need not be true. Consider a function which has $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=x^2$ as second derivative (e.g. by integrating). The second derivative is then nonnegative, hence the graph does not have an inflection point.